# Language not changing in app Android Studio

Tags: android, locale

So basically i have a spinner that chooses between three languages, here's the code, my language does change but it appears it is loading the language just not the resources i have set for it.

**My Code**

```
private void setLocale(String localeName){
            if (localeName.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                return;
            Resources resources = getResources();
            Locale locale = new Locale(localeName);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            android.content.res.Configuration config = new
                    android.content.res.Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
            //restart base activity
            this.finish();
            this.startActivity(this.getIntent());
        }
```

One of the languages strings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Tabibi</string>
    <string name="already_have_an_account">تمتلك حساب؟</string>
    <string name="join">إنشاء حساب</string>
    <string name="login">تسجيل الدخول</string>
    <string name="language">اللغة</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create One Application Class which is set language to all activity

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    private static Application applicationInstance;

    public static synchronized Application getInstance() {
        return applicationInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        applicationInstance = this;
    }

    public void initAppLanguage(Context context) {
        LocaleUtils.initialize(context, LocaleUtils.getSelectedLanguageId());
    }

}
```

LocalteUtils Class is used to set the selected language in shared preferences and set the english language by default

```
public class LocaleUtils {

    public static final String ENGLISH = "en";
    public static final String FRENCH = "fr";
    public static final String SPANISH = "es";


    public static void initialize(Context context, @LocaleDef String defaultLanguage) {
        setLocale(context, defaultLanguage);
    }

    public static boolean setLocale(Context context, @LocaleDef String language) {
        return updateResources(context, language);
    }

    private static boolean updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        configuration.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return true;
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @StringDef({ENGLISH, FRENCH, SPANISH})
    public @interface LocaleDef {
        String[] SUPPORTED_LOCALES = {ENGLISH, FRENCH, SPANISH};
    }


    private static SharedPreferences getDefaultSharedPreference(Context context) {
        if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext()) != null)
            return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        else
            return null;
    }

    public static void setSelectedLanguageId(String id){
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreference(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("app_language_id", id);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String getSelectedLanguageId(){
        return getDefaultSharedPreference(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext())
                .getString("app_language_id", "en");
    }
}
```

Onclick of spinner selected language just set language to shared preferences and restart activity like this

```
LocaleUtils.setSelectedLanguageId("fr");
        Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
        startActivity(i);
```

Last set Preference language to MainActivity using Application Instance.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Application.getInstance().initAppLanguage(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

In manifest file Add Application

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

This code is working fine in android pie also.
Happy Coding...

Comment: sorry for taking too long, thanks lots it works perfectly <3

Comment: this code apply language only in context, and Application.getInstance().initAppLanguage(this); context contains current activity and to apply language for all activities, this code must be run in every activity. How can apply this code one time for all activities?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did work for me. However, for more compatibility i thought replacing the line:

```
context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
```

in `LocaleUtils` with the code below would make changing the configuration work with more android versions (API 15)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
    context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
} else {          
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app working file in development mode and when you publish this build then not reflect the language .
then you want to add these lines for more understanding [https://stackov12748481](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74286621/12748481)

```
android{
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```