# Android problem with applying language programmatically in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I was making app's language able to be changed by users. So, I added language configuration thing to my app. I added spinner to configuration screen, and spinner has list of language (Auto, English, Chinese, etc). I save selected item's position in shared preference (default value is 0 which is Auto). In every activity class, I add override method *attachBaseContext(newBase: Context)*. This code is how I override attachBaseContext

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
    val shared = newBase.getSharedPreferences("configuration",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val position = shared?.getInt("Language",0) ?: 0

    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.langChange(newBase,position)
```

and this is *LocaleManager*

```
object LocaleManager {
    fun langChange(context: Context, position: Int): ContextWrapper {
        var lang: String = if(position < StaticStore.lang.size)
            StaticStore.lang[position]
        else
            StaticStore.lang[0]

        if(lang == "")
            lang = Resources.getSystem().configuration.locales.get(0).language

        val config = context.resources.configuration

        if(lang != "") {
            val loc = Locale(lang)

            Locale.setDefault(loc)
            config.setLocale(loc)

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                setSystemLocale(config,loc)
            } else {
                setSystemLocaleLegacy(config,loc)
            }
        }

        var c = context

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            c = context.createConfigurationContext(config)
        } else {
            context.resources.updateConfiguration(config,context.resources.displayMetrics)
        }

        return ContextWrapper(c)
    }

    private fun setSystemLocaleLegacy(config: Configuration, loc: Locale) {
        config.locale = loc
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    fun setSystemLocale(config: Configuration, loc: Locale) {
        config.setLocale(loc)
    }
}
```

StaticStore is java class which stores static variables. In StaticStore,

```
public static String[] lang = {"","en","zh","ja"};
```

This way worked fine when I was using Java. I thought converting my Android project to Kotlin will be good, so I converted activity classes first. But for some reason, this way isn't working now.

I searched about this problem for hours.
Tried these answers and didn't work

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56251029/12781977 (Sets locale in class which extends *Application*)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40849142/12781977 (This is similar with my code, but it uses *LocaleList*, not *Locale*)

But fortunately, I tried this way and it finally worked

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
    val shared = newBase.getSharedPreferences(StaticStore.CONFIG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val lang = shared?.getInt("Language",0) ?: 0

    val config = Configuration() //Create new Configuration
    var language = StaticStore.lang[lang]

    if(language == "")
        language = Resources.getSystem().configuration.locales.get(0).toString()

    config.setLocale(Locale(language))
    applyOverrideConfiguration(config) //Manually override configuration using "config"

    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.langChange(newBase,shared?.getInt("Language",0) ?: 0))
}
```

It doesn't print any error when I open specific activity **first time**.
Reopening same activity (like go back to main screen and re-enter to configuration screen) prints error

```
2020-01-26 11:26:55.619 28216-28216/com.mandarin.myapp E/AppCompatDelegate: updateForNightMode. Calling applyOverrideConfiguration() failed with an exception. Will fall back to using Resources.updateConfiguration()
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Override configuration has already been set
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.applyOverrideConfiguration(ContextThemeWrapper.java:99)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.updateForNightMode(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2281)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.applyDayNight(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2170)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachBaseContext(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:334)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.attachBaseContext(AppCompatActivity.java:98)
    at com.mandarin.myapp.ConfigScreen.attachBaseContext(ConfigScreen.kt:371)
    at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:6598)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2580)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I understand this error, but I **have to** use *applyOverrideConfiguration(config)* to solve locale setting problem. Weird thing is that even though this error is printed, app won't crash, but it disturbs me a lot.

Anyway, because of this error, I tried to use *applyOverrideConfiguration(config)* only once using static boolean. It can change language fine when I open activity first time. But when I reopen same activity, it shows default language again (English is device's language). So this means that only *applyOverrideConfiguration(config)* can change language...

Actually I don't need to call this method when *super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.langChange(newBase,position)* working fine, but it's not working for some reason.

Are there any ways to use *applyOverrideConfiguration* without printing error? Or are there any ways to solve changing language problem?