# How to change language locale in Jetpack Compose

Tags: locale, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change language programmatically in Jetpack Compose. I've read quite some posts and watch videos but still can't find the way to do it. (The post and video are in Android view system.)

[How to change language in kotlin (locale)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249754/how-to-change-language-in-kotlin-locale)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxPzi2h0Vvc

I want my app works like below image. After clicking the language, the whole app will change the language. Below code is the clickable's part. What should I do in this clickable part and MainActivity.kt?

```
@Composable
fun LanguageScreen(
    navController: NavController,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val langList = arrayOf("English", "繁體中文", "简体中文", "日本語")
    var items by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            langList.map {
                LanguageItem(
                    title = it,
                    isSelected = false
                )
            }
        )
    }
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        items(items.size) { i ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable {

                        items = items.mapIndexed { j, item ->
                            if (i == j) {
                                item.copy(isSelected = true)
                            } else item.copy(isSelected = false)
                        }

                        if (i == 0) {
                            setLocaleLang("", context)
                        } else if (i == 1) {
                            setLocaleLang("zh-rTW", context)
                        } else if (i == 2) {
                            setLocaleLang("zh-rCN", context)
                        } else {
                            setLocaleLang("ja", context)
                        }

                    }
                    .padding(16.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Text(text = items[i].title, fontSize = 20.sp)
                if (items[i].isSelected) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Check,
                        contentDescription = "Selected",
                        tint = Color.Blue,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(1.dp)
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
            )
        }
    }
}


fun setLocaleLang(lang: String, context: Context) {
    val locale = Locale(lang)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val resources = context.resources
    val configuration = resources.configuration
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)

    val editor = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    editor.putString("My_Lang", lang)
    editor.apply()
}

fun loadLocale(context: Context) {
    val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val language = sharedPreferences.getString("My_Lang", "")
    setLocaleLang(language!!, context)
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @ExperimentalFoundationApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        loadLocale(this)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SpanishTravelTheme {
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5kcO.png

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary part from the clickable lambda. It confuses people.

Comment: PS: I don't think there is any difference for Compose. You do it the exact same way you did in the previous system.

Comment: Per-app language feature was just added to the latest Android API 33, that is still on Developer preview. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71151685/5038317

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change app language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

1. Create a helper object

`LocaleUtils.kt`

```
object LocaleUtils {

// [AppPrefs] is sharedpreferences or datastore
fun setLocale(c: Context, pref: AppPrefs) = updateResources(c, pref.language ?: "en") //use locale codes

private fun updateResources(context: Context, language: String) {
    context.resources.apply {
        val locale = Locale(language)
        val config = Configuration(configuration)

        context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        config.setLocale(locale)
        context.resources.updateConfiguration(config, displayMetrics)
    }
  }
}
```

2. Call `setLocale` inside `setContent` to change the language at runtime.

```
    setContent {
        LocaleUtils.setLocale(LocalContext.current, viewModel.pref)
```

3. To change the App language

```
    fun changeAppLanguage(languageISO: String) {
        sharedPrefs.edit().putString(LANGUAGE_KEY, languageISO).apply()
    }
```

Please remember to use language ISO 639-1 Code

here's a list of Locale codes
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/client-side/localization

**UPDATE:**

now you can just use `AppCompatDelegate` from `androidx.appcompat`

Example:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("en"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `updateConfiguration` is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to this:

Sample App: https://github.com/Eganathan/Compose-LocalizationSample
Doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages

1. Create Respective String Resources:
   res > new > Android Resourse File > Select Locale and create a string.xml files
2. in res/xml create a new file called locales_config.xml and fill in the locale of your choices.

**example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<locale-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <locale android:name="en" />
    <locale android:name="ta" />
    <locale android:name="hi" />
    <locale android:name="ml" />
</locale-config>
```

3. moving to gradle:

```
android{
...
   androidResources {
        generateLocaleConfig = true 
    }
...

  defaultConfig {
...
  resourceConfigurations.plus(listOf("ta", "en", "hi","your-langauge-tag"))

  }

}
```

4. Moving to Manifest file:

```
   ... <application ...>
     <service
       android:name="androidx.appcompat.app.AppLocalesMetadataHolderService"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="autoStoreLocales"
                android:value="true" />
     </service>
</application>
```

5. add the following function anywhere you like:

```
fun localeSelection(context: Context, localeTag: String) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        context.getSystemService(LocaleManager::class.java).applicationLocales =
            LocaleList.forLanguageTags(localeTag)
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(
            LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(localeTag)
        )
    }
}
```

6. now where ever you want to pass the on click just call the above funciton:

```
localeSelection(context = context, localeTag = currentLocale.value)
```

example:

```
val context = LocalContext.current

Button(onClick = {
                localeSelection(context = context, localeTag = Locale("ta").toLanguageTag())
            }) {
                Text(text = "Tamil")
            }
```

Please refer to my sample app or the Doc if you have any doubts.

Doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages

PS: Here the locale is stored and managed by the system itself and I'm using Kotlin script.

Comment: Dont works for API < 33. Don't forget to add `android:localeConfig="@xml/locales_config"` in `<activity>` in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `unqualifiedResLocale=en` in `res/ressources.properties`

Comment: Works for API < 33 with using `AppCompatActivity()` as MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 val context = LocalContext.current
 Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable {
                           val locale = Locale(language) //Here I assume you have access to the language you want
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val resources = context.getResources()
        val configuration = resources.getConfiguration()
        configuration.locale = locale
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics())
                    }
                    .padding(16.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            )
```

Comment: I think you were missing the `LocalContext.current`.

Comment: I add your suggestion and LocalContext.current. However the language is still not changed. I think I need to recreate the activity or add something to MainActivity.kt. But I don't know how to do this part specifically.

Comment: I see another post use `recreate()` under the code and in onCreate. I can't find the way to use it in Jetpack Compose. What do you suggest?

Comment: Check if the language changes when you pause the activity, then resume. To do this, just press the home button on the activity, then open it back from the recents menu

Comment: I update my code as above. It's still not working. How should I find the problem?  Thank you