# How do I select a language in OSRM's RoadManager

Tags: java, kotlin, osmdroid, osrm, osmbonuspack

I need to force OSRM to switch the language in `road.mNodes.mInstructions` to English in order to work with English TTS. How do I achieve that in Kotlin? I'm using OSRMRoadManager from OSMBonusPack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually managed to find a workaround which suits my needs, without needing to subclass OSRMRoadManager and all that. For anyone with the same problem - I've switched the language using Locale, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249754/how-to-change-language-in-kotlin-locale). Nevertheless, I think it's probably something that should be in OSMBonusPack as an option, in case one wants to preserve the default language in some other parts of the app. I can try looking into the lib myself.

Comment: You don't need to post this as another answer to the question. To respond to the person who answered, you can put it up as a comment on the answer. You can have this answer (which actually is a comment/reply) deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm new here. My answer does actually contain the answer to my question, though. I can edit it and delete the first sentence and in my opinion it should be classified as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obvious answer.
Basically, you need to change the way DIRECTIONS hashmap is initialized.

Suggestion : you could subclass OSRMRoadManager, adapting buildInstructions(int maneuver, String roadName), to use your own DIRECTIONS object.

If you see a simple change to do inside the lib (adding a "language" option somewhere), don't hesitate to push a PR.