# Change app language programmatically in Android old versions

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am having a trouble with changing app language programmatically on android versions under api.23 (currently testing on device with android 5) I have no idea what to do, so here is my code:


**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PreferenceRepository preferenceRepository;
    @SuppressLint({"NonConstantResourceId", "SourceLockedOrientationActivity"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        preferenceRepository = new PreferenceRepository(this);
        //Sets selected by user language on start
        setLocale(preferenceRepository.loadLocale());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initialization
        RadioButton GeLang = findViewById(R.id.GeorgianLang);
        RadioButton EnLang = findViewById(R.id.EnglishLang);
        RadioGroup LanguageApp = findViewById(R.id.Language);

        //Checks Radio button according to app language
        if (Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage().equals("ქართული")){
            GeLang.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            EnLang.setChecked(true);
        }

        //Changes language according to checked button
        LanguageApp.setOnCheckedChangeListener((LanguageApp1, i) -> {
            switch (i) {
                case R.id.GeorgianLang:
                    setLocale("ka");
                    recreate();
                    break;
                case R.id.EnglishLang:
                    setLocale("en");
                    recreate();
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    //Updates configuration and loads the checked language
    private void setLocale(String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        preferenceRepository.setLocale(language);
    }
}
```

**PreferenceReposytory.class:**

```
public class PreferenceRepository {
    SharedPreferences mySharedPref ;
    public PreferenceRepository(Context context) {
        mySharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("filename",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    //Loads language when app starts
    public String loadLocale() {
        return mySharedPref.getString("My_Language", "");

    }

    //Saves state when language is changed
    public void setLocale(String language){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("My_Language", language);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

I'd like to thank you in advance for your assistance and I'm looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Comment: what the problem that you got when run code sir?

Comment: Basicly the problem is that the language is not chaning on android 5 Lolipop, on android 11 everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56057127/language-not-changing-in-app-android-studio/56087402) see which one wiil help you and let me know if that didn't help you

Comment: None of these helped, sorry :(