# How to globally change language in Android app

Tags: android

I have such code, and its work fine, but it change language only in context which was applied. I need to run this code in all activities.
How can i change language in all app?
I run this code in MainActivity.

```
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        configuration.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return true;
```

I took this code from answer on question:
[Language not changing in app Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56057127/language-not-changing-in-app-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an answer that would fit here because what you're asking is essentially supporting multiple languages for an app. I recommend searching youtube for tutorials or if you have no problem reading the official documentation then the  the [Android Developer website](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages) is probably you best bet.

Comment: Yes, it takes default system language, but I want to implement language change in application

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you have BaseActivity class and In that class override method attachBaseContext() which sends a Context object which can be used in the activity.

`override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) { super.attachBaseContext(LangContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, LangManager.currentLang)) }`

Comment: but any other chances? Maybe via Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration() ?